# "How great it would be" x "How great would it be". Do both have the same meaning?

Tags: difference

I have seen both forms being used in written English and apparently both with the same meaning, like in the sentences below:

*I know you have been extremely busy, but just imagine **how great it would be** if we could spend an entire weekend together.*

*I know you have been extremely busy, but just imagine **how great would it be** if we could spend an entire weekend together.*

I'm confused. Wouldn't the use of **how great would it be** turn the phrase into a question?

Answer (score 1):

> imagine how great it would be

Correct.

It's a type of "statement" where you are saying it would be great.

> how great would it be?

On it's own, this is a question.  Notice how the words are rearranged, and "would" appears before "it".  You might investigate grammatical "inversion", which is most common with the question form of sentences.

In this case, it turns your main sentence into a question which ought to have a question mark at the end.

> I know you have been extremely busy, but just imagine...    (pause)
> How great would it be if we could spend an entire weekend together?

The speaker interrupts themselves, and then starts a brand new sentence where they ask "how great would it be?"

So, if you prefer to have one single complete sentence, the first format is preferable.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the explanations. And yes, that’s exactly how I learned. But I was intrigued because I have found many texts in English where the “would it be” form is used in an affirmative sentence. Here are some examples:

Imagine how great would it be closing the week with the taste of one of these!

Imagine how great would it be for you to go through your day feeling alive & energetic all the time and with a big smile on your face.

Imagine how great would it be to document all exciting milestones from your baby`s first year!

Does that make any sense?

Comment: @Itamar, those could simply be errors.  mistakes.    Another explanation is that sometimes people change "statements" into "questions", to create an effect.   And what is this effect...?   Maybe they are unsure of themselves.  Or, sometimes it's because they think it sounds cute or interesting.